# Regarding JavaScript, Is there an easier way to code this?

Tags: javascript

I'm learning JavaScript in depth and I'm wondering if i've coded this the best way possible? I tried creating my own fade out animation based off of data attribute values. Please let me know if theres a way to simplify this. Thanks

Don't mention jQuery please. I'm trying to learn JavaScript, I'm well aware that jQuery already made this.

HTML

```
<div id="box" style="background-color: black; width: 100px; height: 100px;"></div>

<div data-action="fadeout" style="background-color: red; width: 100px; height: 100px;"></div>

<div data-action="fadeout" style="background-color: green; width: 100px; height: 100px;"></div>

<div data-action="fadut" style="background-color: green; width: 100px; height: 100px;"></div>
```

JavaScript

```
var x = document.querySelectorAll("[data-action]");
console.log(x);

for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++){

    var j = x[i];

    if (j.getAttribute("data-action") === "fadeout"){
        j.addEventListener("click", function(){
            fadeout(this);
        });
    }

}

function fadeout(x){

    var i = 1;
    x.style.position = "relative";

    fade();

    function fade(){
        console.log("hi");
        if (i > 0){

            x.style.opacity = i.toString();

            setTimeout(function(){
                fade();
                i -= .1;
            }, 50);

        } 
        else{
            x.style.display = "none";
        }
    }


}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qdjLyg2o/

Comment: Please read [ask] and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: *"I'm trying to learn JavaScript, I'm well aware that jQuery already made this."* When you're using jQuery, you **are** using JavaScript (unless you're using CoffeeScript or TypeScript or similar). If you're trying to learn the DOM, that's fine, but JavaScript != DOM. JavaScript is a **language**. jQuery and the DOM provide **APIs** you can use with that language.

Comment: opacity need not be a string. `document.querySelectorAll("[data-action='fadeout']");` shaves your conditional. but really, we could do it 95% in CSS  a `[data-action='fadeout']{ opacity: 1; transition: 500ms opacity;} [data-action='fadeout'].hidden { opacity:0;} ` then add the _hidden_ class to the element in the fade() function.

Comment: "I'm wondering if i've coded this the best way possible." Hah! 95% of your code will look like shit in three months, almost regardless of experience. There are different patterns of structuring (and thinking about) code. Different people have different preferences for what's best. Different *languages* have different idioms for the same problems. Languages change. Tastes change. The problem you're trying to solve changes. The best you can hope for is code that's correct, readable, and comprehendable, and even that's hard.

Comment: Maybe I just didn't make it clear what I was trying to do, I know jQuery is JavaScript, I'm trying to recreate the jQuery fadeout. I'm mostly interested in finding out a way to simplify my code, I just feel like there's got to be a shorter way to do this using just JavaScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS animations or CSS transitions would be a better way to implement a fade effect: they would be smoother and use less CPU, and mean less code for you too. Generally avoid animations in JavaScript unless they absolutely cannot be accomplished using CSS's animation or transition repertoire.

```
*[data-action="fadeout"] {
    opacity: 1.0;
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out; /* your code changed opacity by 0.1 every 50ms, that's 0.0-1.0 over 500ms */
}
*[data-action='fadeout'].clicked {
    opacity: 0.0;
}
```

Then use JavaScript to set the `.clicked` class:

```
var divs = document.querySelectorAll("[data-action='fadeout']");
for(var i=0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    divs[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
        this.className = "clicked";
    });
}
```